# $rootscope watch doesn't work for scond time

Tags: angularjs

I am very new in Angularjs. I defined $rootscope watcher in controller. First time(during page load) it will work means alert display but after changes in `$rootScope.cartItems` it  doesn't work.

```
eshopApp.controller('cartCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, cartService, $cookies) {

$rootScope.$watch('cartItems', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    cartService.cartSubTotal(function (data) {
        $scope.cartSubTotalVal = data;
        alert('total '+$scope.cartSubTotalVal);
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Where do you define `cartItems`? What does your cartService do?

Comment: Your cartitems shouldn't be in rootScope in the first place. Use a service to share data across the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `true` in third parameter. e.g

```
$rootScope.$watch('cartItems', function (newVal, oldVal) {
cartService.cartSubTotal(function (data) {

        $scope.cartSubTotalVal = data;
        alert('total '+$scope.cartSubTotalVal);
       });
     });
  },true);
```

Answer (score 1):

On an entirely unrelated note: Don't use $rootScope watchers or watchers in general. Only a really small part of use cases actually requires watchers :
Check out this article for more information :

[You dont need watchers](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html)